# Why does this python comprehension repeat the user input multiple times?

Tags: python

I'm asking a user to enter a list of security groups using python:

```
sg_list_input = str(input("Enter a comma separated list of security groups to add: "))
```

The user enters a list like this:

```
sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb
```

I then try to srtip out the spaces in the list with this line:

```
sg_list_input = [sg_list_input.strip(' ') for sg in sg_list_input]
```

If I print the list comprehension afterwards the list is repeated over and over again:

```
SG LIST INPUT AFTER COMPREHENSTION: ['sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb', 'sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb']
```

Why is this happening and how do I correct it?

Comment: You used the wrong variable in the comprehension.

Comment: Sidenote, `str(input())` is redundant since `input()` returns a `str`.

Comment: `sg_list_input` is not a `list`, it's a `str`.  Because of this `for sg in sg_list_input` will loop over each _letter_ in the `str`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually iterating through the string object you got from the input, so for each character on the string you are adding the entire string to the list.

Instead you should first split by comma and then strip whitespaces from each element of the list as follows,

```
sg_list_input = [sg.strip(' ') for sg in sg_list_input.split(',')]
```

Keep on coding!

Answer (score 6):

Basically, your list comprehension is stripping the whole `sg_list_input`, not just one element `sg`. Also, the user input will be interpreted as a string, so you'll need to split it up into a list. Try this instead:

```
sg_list_input = [sg.strip(' ') for sg in sg_list_input.split(",")]
```

Answer (score 4):

You're apparently not splitting the input list, so it's adding `sg_list_input.strip(' ')` for every *character* in the input, rather than every comma-delimited item, so that's why so many copies are appearing in the list.

Also, `strip(' ')` does not remove all spaces, just trailing and leading ones.

If you want to remove all spaces from `sg_list_input`, you can do a `replace()`:

```
sg_list_input = sg_list_input.replace(" ", "")
# input: "a, b, c, d, e"
# output: "a,b,c,d,e"
```

Then, if you want each item to be in a list, you can use `split()`:

```
sg_list_input = sg_list_input.split(",")
# input: "a,b,c,d,e"
# output: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Alternatively, as others pointed out, you can use list comprehension to do it all in one line.

As for why I'm not just splitting on `", "`: a user may or may not use spaces, so this way it takes care of both cases, where the input is `"a,b,c,d"` or `"a, b, c, d"`. If you split on `", "` then it wouldn't work in every case. The input prompt says to enter a comma delimited list, which users may interpret differently. Most people naturally want to add a space, but someone who takes things literally, and might have worked with CSV files, could be more inclined to not add spaces.

Answer (score 1):

fyi i dont really think list comprehension is needed here

```
new_str = sg_list_input.replace(' ', '')
print(new_str.split(','))
```

pretty sure this accomplishes what you are looking for

Comment: I edited your answer to split on a comma, since without doing so your answer was incorrect.

Comment: I thought the user was attempting to convert the string to a list and strip the whitespace? split() will split on any whitespace if left unspecified, splitting on comma will leave the white space.

Comment: But you were stripping the whitespace first with `replace(' ', ''), so the `split()` wouldn't have split anything. If you had removed the _commas_, via `replace(',', '')`, then it would've worked.